# wg-quick "wait: pid 9185 is not a child if this shell" on Debian 8.11

Tags: bash, debian

All work on Debian 9+ without problem with identical setting and install methods.

When I try to start service

```
systemctl start wg-quick@wg0
```

It shows error in journal:

```
wg-quick[9290]: [#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
wg-quick[9290]: [#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
wg-quick[9290]: /usr/bin/wg-quick: line 251: wait: pid 9308 is not a child ...hell
wg-quick[9290]: [#] ip link delete dev wg0
```

Also it shows similar error when you start it so (also exec script wg-qucik):

```
wg-quick ip wg0
```

This problem with `wait`.
Additionally I installed clear Debian 8.11 to VirtualBox. There is the same error. But on Debian 9 it works correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[I found a commit cancellation](https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-tools/commit/91fbeb4a926b8a75274d012a3994ef337dca51d9)

I think problem in bash < 4.4
because on Debian 8 version - *4.3.30*, on Debian 9 - *4.4.12*

For update run by root:

```
WGQUICKPATH=$(which wg-quick)
mv "$WGQUICKPATH" "$WGQUICKPATH.bak"
wget -O "$WGQUICKPATH" "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WireGuard/wireguard-tools/master/src/wg-quick/linux.bash"
chmod +x "$WGQUICKPATH"
```